# How to create custom domain email address on gsuite for education using PHP script

Tags: google-workspace

I am trying to create email addresses from my script automatically on Gsuite for education.

I have tried all that is here https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert?authuser=4#try-it

If I try it online from the link above, it gets created. but when I try with my own code, it does not

```
<?php
$post_fields = json_encode(array(
    'name'       =>array('familyName'=>'Dan', 'givenName'=>'Foster'),
    'password'        => '1234567890',
    'primaryEmail'    => 'dan.foster@domain.com',
    'agreedToTerms'   => false,
    'isMailboxSetup'  => false
));

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?key=[ASCCESS_key]",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post_fields,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer [AUTHENTICATION TOKEN]",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

I get the below error after execution

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "authError",
                "message": "Invalid Credentials",
                "locationType": "header",
                "location": "Authorization"
            }
        ],
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Invalid Credentials"
    }
}
```

How can I bypass the OAuth login as my account is the admin and this code is executed from the backend.

***Update

I got it to work finally;

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.dirname(__FILE__).'/google/credentials.json');
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setSubject($this->adminEmail);
        $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER);
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

        return $client;
```

Comment: You cannot bypass OAuth. However, I would use a service account and the API and not try to do stuff with curl. Using the REST API is fine, you just have to manage all the details. However, the credentials that you are using do not have the correct permissions and of course, you left that out of the details of your question.

Comment: I gave thew credentials am using the correct permission though, also can you point me to any documentation to implement with rest and service account

Comment: Search for "G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation". This will show you the steps to set up a service account with the correct rights for G Suite.

Comment: now I am getting this error: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden", "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api" } }

Comment: You did not setup delegation correctly. Go back to the documentation and follow it exactly. One wrong step and you will get errors.